# SqlException in DBeaver24.0.1 when doing datasets connection

Tags: sql, database, db2, dbeaver

I was trying to do datasets connection in DBeaver.

I was choosing the driver name Db2 for LUW.

After i enter all the information like host name, database namem database username and passowrd, then i press test connection button to do datasets connect.

I get the error "SqlException", the error in detail is "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException".

I wish someone that is good in using the app DBeaver to help me solve this issue.

Tq

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with SQL Server?

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Comment: What version of db2 are you running? Are you sure you have the right port number?

Comment: How have you proved that your Db2-server is __really__ listening on that port?  This is not programming. Just basic configuration.

Comment: @Isolated 

I install the db2 server editor and the version is v11.5.7_ntx64_server_dec. 

For the port number, i have check my port number in service file in the notepad. 
I using this "C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services" to locate the service file.

Comment: @mao I not sure is my Db2-server is listening on the port. May I know how you make sure the Db2-server is listening on that port ? My port number is 25000.

Comment: Study the docs!  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tcpip-setting-communication-protocols-db2-instance   . To verify that Db2-server is __really__listening on a specific port, use the `netstat` command in a cmd.exe window. Refer to the Microsoft website for the docs for netstat.

Comment: @mao i had use the `netstat -a | findstr "25000"` to find did the db2 listening to the port.  I get two result one is   `  TCP    0.0.0.0:25000          DESKTOP-I3BLGFJ:0      LISTENING` and other one is ` TCP    127.0.0.1:25000        DESKTOP-I3BLGFJ:49934  TIME_WAIT`. It seem the db2 is not listening to the port. Do you know how to configure it ?

Comment: Verify the Windows firewall has rules to allow inbound and outbound traffic on IP for that port number. Use Windows documentation to learn how to do this.  Separately, append to your Db2 connection string in Dbeaver `retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;` (use Dbeaver docs to learn how to configure additional connection settings).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mao I have set the rules to allow inbound and outbound traffic on IP for that port number and i add retrieve `MessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true` in the Dbeaver. But i still get the error "SqlException" when i try to connect the datasets.

Comment: Check spelling of `retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;` (if __correctly__ set it shows better error message). Try DBVisualizer or SquirrelSQL, or use a jdbc test program (to eliminate DBeaver temporarily). The symptom can happen if there is something in the environment you are omitting from the question.  __EDIT__ the question (do not use comments to add facts), add build and edition of MS-Windows, its regional-settings (locale), and whether there are any messages of type ERROR in the db2diag.log files on your Db2-server (look in the Db2 online documentation to find the location).

Comment: @mao i just solve the error. I found out i didnt create a datasets in db2 frist before i try to run the dbeaver. Thank for your help.